# Getting unknown error regarding dll file

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll

When I try to run my application, I am getting an unknown error. The error message is as below.

> Error 1   The type
>   'ASP.*usercontrols*_21_0_unscheduled_angio_event_sheet_ascx'
>   exists in both
>   'c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\nanostentv02\f1f02035\c7751ed\App_Web_zxaxdb4a.dll' and
>   'c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\nanostentv02\f1f02035\c7751ed\App_Web_4odgbrwn.dll' C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\NanoStentV02_PL\CRO\21_0_UNSCHEDULED_ANGIO_EVENT_SHEET.aspx 12

The page code for 21_0_UNSCHEDULED_ANGIO_EVENT_SHEET.aspx   12 is as below.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/_PL/CRO/_CRO.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeFile="21_0_UNSCHEDULED_ANGIO_EVENT_SHEET.aspx.cs" Inherits="_PL_CRO_21_0_UNSCHEDULED_ANGIO_EVENT_SHEET" %>

<%@ Register Src="../../_UserControls/_21_0_UNSCHEDULED_ANGIO_EVENT_SHEET.ascx" TagName="_21_0_UNSCHEDULED_ANGIO_EVENT_SHEET"
TagPrefix="uc1" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ChildContent1" runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ChildContent2" runat="Server">
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnPatientID" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnPatientCode" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnCEType" runat="server" />
<uc1:_21_0_UNSCHEDULED_ANGIO_EVENT_SHEET ID="_21_0_UNSCHEDULED_ANGIO_EVENT_SHEET1"
    runat="server" />
</asp:Content>
```

Earlier it was working fine but suddenly it stopped working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to clean solution in Visual Studio and build project again. Libraries cached

Comment: I have rebuild the solution...But still same problem.

Comment: @f0rza..I have re-built solution without clearing it...How to clear solution in visual studio? Will it loose anything??

Answer (score 0):

check these

> CodeFile="21_0_UNSCHEDULED_ANGIO_EVENT_SHEET.aspx.cs"

and

> <%@ Register
>   Src="../../_UserControls/_21_0_UNSCHEDULED_ANGIO_EVENT_SHEET.ascx"

may be there some assembly name conflict. Try with changing the name of one of them. again Rebuild the solution.